# Android AppWidget Wierd Behavior

Tags: android, memory, widget, reset

I have created a widget that retrieves html raw data and parses it out. The data is displayed to the widget correctly but when i launch the config activity of the widget and exit back out, the widget layout is reset and nothing is displayed on the widget, all text was deleted. The widget works flawlessly on android 4.0 and does not have this problem but on 2.3.3 it has this behavior. Any ideas as to what the problem is and how to fix it?

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

       WidgetIds = appWidgetIds;
       try {BUP.backupWidgetIdLength(context,  WidgetIds.length);} catch (Exception e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
       for(int i = 0; i < WidgetIds.length; i++)
       {
        try {BUP.backupWidgetIds(context, WidgetIds[i], i);
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
       }


          super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
          //updateWidget(context,appWidgetIds);
          final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
          for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
              int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

              updateWidget(context,appWidgetId);

          }  


static void updateWidget(Context context,int appWidgetIds)
{


    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MySchedule.class);

        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);
        try
        {

            Intent sch = new Intent(context, FullSchedule.class);
            sch.setAction(schedule_Click);
            sch.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            sch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Rlayout4,PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),appWidgetIds,sch,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));   

            Intent f = new Intent(context, MyConfig.class);
            f.setAction(Settings);
            f.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            f.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Rlayout2,PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),appWidgetIds,f,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)); 

            Intent s = new Intent(context, MySchedule.class);
            s.setAction(leftSchedule_CLICK);
            s.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pis = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),appWidgetIds, s,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Change_Schedule,pis);


            Intent t = new Intent(context, MySchedule.class);
            t.setAction(rightSchedule_CLICK);
            t.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent pit = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),appWidgetIds, t,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Change_Schedule2,pit);

            Intent u = new Intent(context, MySchedule.class);
            u.setAction(Update_Schedule);
            u.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
            PendingIntent piu = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(),appWidgetIds, u,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.updateView,piu);

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetMan = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MySchedule.class);
            appWidgetMan.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Error_OnUpdate",e.getMessage());
        }

}

   }
```

`

Comment: please show the code you use to update your widget (where you use RemoteViews).

Comment: Im guessing it has something to do with how older versions of android manages memory because android 4.0 works fine but im not for sure. This is the case on other devices running 4.0.